# Code is printing out largest subscript of the array when it should be printing maximum and minimum

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to print the largest and smallest values on an array, as well as their respective subscripts. I'm running into a problem where my code, though printing the highest and lowest values of the array, is returning the largest subscript (regardless of value) for both maximum and minimum arrays. The problem lies somewhere in the for loops, below.

```
int max = arrayOfNumbers[0];
        int min = arrayOfNumbers[0];
        int indexMax = 0;
        int indexMin = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfNumbers.length; i++) {
    if (max < arrayOfNumbers[i])
        max = arrayOfNumbers[i];
        indexMax = i;
}
for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfNumbers.length; i++) {
    if (min > arrayOfNumbers[i])
        min = arrayOfNumbers[i];
        indexMin = i;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
int max = arrayOfNumbers[0];
int min = arrayOfNumbers[0];
int indexMax = 0;
int indexMin = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfNumbers.length; i++) {
    if (max < arrayOfNumbers[i]) {
        max = arrayOfNumbers[i];
        indexMax = i;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfNumbers.length; i++) {
    if (min > arrayOfNumbers[i]) {
        min = arrayOfNumbers[i];
        indexMin = i;
    }
}
```

You forgot to put both lines after the `if`s into braces. Each time the code inside the loops executed, the current index had been written into both `indexMax` and `indexMin`, and that's why after the loops finished, they contained the "largest subscript".

Comment: -1, rather tell him how to figure out the source of the problem instead of providing a blind copy&paste solution...

Comment: Well Ondrej, I had the general syntax of it right. It's not like I was asking for even a whole loop. I just forgot a set of braces.. it's my fault for even asking the question when the answer was right in front of me, not his for pointing out the obvious

Comment: The only thing he added was 4 braces, -1 isn't needed for such a small correction

Comment: @OndrejTucny While you was busy downvoting my CORRECT answer, I was writing the explanation. Thank you for rewarding my effort with a downvote.

Comment: I will as soon it lets me (answers aren't usually made this fast!)